# Webstorm Uglify after Traceur compiler

Tags: javascript, webstorm, uglifyjs, traceur

I am using googles traceur (https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler) and have set up webstorm to watch traceur files and output them to a "public" directory.

Here is my traceur watcher arguments

```
--out public/$FilePathRelativeToProjectRoot$ --script $FilePathRelativeToProjectRoot$
```

This is working, however I want to run "uglify-js" on the outputted file from the traceur compiler.

My uglify arguments:

```
$ProjectFileDir$\public\$FileRelativePath$ -o $ProjectFileDir$\$FileRelativePath$
```

However instead of getting the one /public/ it runs with these arguments in the watcher

```
uglifyjs.cmd C:\Users\Dylan\WebstormProjects\circleUI\public\public\js\lib\easyA.js -o C:\Users\Dylan\WebstormProjects\circleUI\public\js\lib\easyA.js
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the watcher to listen to changes in certain file(s) only, you need to create a custom scope (Settings/Scopes) including these files only and set this scope to file watcher. And use

> $FileName$ -o `<output path>`

as uglifier atguments

With your settings, the non-existing files will be passed to uglifier in most cases. For example, let's imagine that the file foo.js located in $ProjectFileDir$/src folder has been modified. As a result, the following input will be passed to uglifier:
$ProjectFileDir$/public/src/foo.js

it's clear that the uglifier will fail then

Comment: I implemented your solution, thanks for the reply! However now the first time the file is uglified it works, and the next time it recreates the file paths relative to it inside of the scope and outputs again. This is proving to be an annoying problem :\

Comment: this, again, means that something is configured wrong. For example, if your watcher overwrites the file it listens to, it will run, and run, and run, ...